# cannot find the right library after adding a repo

Tags: android, gradle

I tried to add a library to an Android project from a GUI.

First, I added a maven repository to a project.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}
```

Second, I tried to add a library using `File > Project Structure...`  But when I queried for a library, I could not find the right library  (it should be from `com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0`).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to paste `implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'` in your app gradle file, It is the file with `build.gradle(Module:app)`

```
dependencies {
    // paste your lib here
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

if it shows some error please update your question, 
hope this will help

### Edit 1

you can also use GUI to change library version after adding it via code

Comment: I'd like to use GUI instead of copy and paste `implementation ...` because I'd like to choose a specific version of a repo.

Comment: @wannik  Iupdated the answer please check. you can change library version using **Project Structure Dialog**

Comment: I don't think that Android Studio GUI knows this library in the repo because when I change the version to 3.0.0, there is no choice for 3.1.0 or any version.